# pull out p-values and r-squared from a linear regression

Tags: r

How do you pull out the p-value (for the significance of the coefficient of the single explanatory variable being non-zero) and R-squared value from a simple linear regression model? For example...

```
x = cumsum(c(0, runif(100, -1, +1)))
y = cumsum(c(0, runif(100, -1, +1)))
fit = lm(y ~ x)
summary(fit)
```

I know that `summary(fit)` *displays* the p-value and R-squared value, but I want to be able to stick these into other variables.

Comment: It only displays the values if you don't assign the output to an object (e.g. `r <- summary(lm(rnorm(10)~runif(10)))` does not display anything).

Answer (score 222, accepted):

**r-squared**: You can return the r-squared value directly from the summary object `summary(fit)$r.squared`. See `names(summary(fit))` for a list of all the items you can extract directly.

**Model p-value:** If you want to obtain the p-value of the overall regression model, 
[this blog post](http://gettinggeneticsdone.blogspot.com/2011/01/rstats-function-for-extracting-f-test-p.html) outlines a function to return the p-value:

```
lmp <- function (modelobject) {
    if (class(modelobject) != "lm") stop("Not an object of class 'lm' ")
    f <- summary(modelobject)$fstatistic
    p <- pf(f[1],f[2],f[3],lower.tail=F)
    attributes(p) <- NULL
    return(p)
}

> lmp(fit)
[1] 1.622665e-05
```

In the case of a simple regression with one predictor, the model p-value and the p-value for the coefficient will be the same.

**Coefficient p-values:** If you have more than one predictor, then the above will return the model p-value, and the p-value for coefficients can be extracted using:

```
summary(fit)$coefficients[,4]
```

Alternatively, you can grab the p-value of coefficients from the `anova(fit)` object in a similar fashion to the summary object above.

Comment: It's a bit better to use `inherits` rather than `class` directly.  And maybe you want `unname(pf(f[1],f[2],f[3],lower.tail=F))`?

Comment: If you prefer a one-liner: `summary(fit)$fstatistic %>% {unname(pf(.[1],.[2],.[3],lower.tail=F))}`

Comment: Or as pipe-less one-liner: `with(summary(fit), pf(fstatistic[1],fstatistic[2],fstatistic[3],lower.tail=F))`

Answer (score 185):

Notice that `summary(fit)` generates an object with all the information you need. The beta, se, t and p vectors are stored in it. Get the p-values by selecting the 4th column of the coefficients matrix (stored in the summary object):

```
summary(fit)$coefficients[,4] 
summary(fit)$r.squared
```

Try `str(summary(fit))` to see all the info that this object contains.

Edit: I had misread Chase's answer which basically tells you how to get to what I give here.

Comment: Note: this is the only method which gives you easy access to the p-value of the intercept as well as the other predictors. By far the best of above.

Comment: This is the RIGHT answer.  The top-rated answer did NOT work for me.

Comment: IF YOU WANT EASY ACCESS TO P-VALUE, USE THIS ANSWER. Why would you go through writing multi-line functions or creating new objects (i.e., anova outputs), when you just have to look a bit harder to find p-value in the summary output itself. To isolate an individual p-value itself, you'd add a row number to Vincent's answer: for example, `summary(fit)$coefficients[1,4] ` for thei ntercept

Comment: Note: this method works for models created using `lm()` but does not work for `gls()` models.

Comment: See [my answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/35518814/4581200) below for an extension of this answer that works for `lm()` AND `gls()`

Comment: Chase's answer returns the p-value of the model, this answer returns the p-value of the coefficients. In the case of a simple regression, they are the same, but in the case of a model with multiple predictors, they are not the same. Thus, both answers are useful depending on what you want to extract.

Answer (score 52):

You can see the structure of the object returned by `summary()` by calling `str(summary(fit))`. Each piece can be accessed using `$`. The p-value for the F statistic is more easily had from the object returned by `anova`.

Concisely, you can do this:

```
rSquared <- summary(fit)$r.squared
pVal <- anova(fit)$'Pr(>F)'[1]
```

Comment: this works only for univariate regressions where the p val of the regression is the same of the predictor

Comment: For some reason this answer does not work when using the summary object from aov

Answer (score 33):

I came across this question while exploring suggested solutions for a similar problem; I presume that for future reference it may be worthwhile to update the available list of answer with a solution utilising the [**`broom`**](https://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/broom/vignettes/broom.html) package.

## Sample code

```
x = cumsum(c(0, runif(100, -1, +1)))
y = cumsum(c(0, runif(100, -1, +1)))
fit = lm(y ~ x)
require(broom)
glance(fit)
```

### Results

```
>> glance(fit)
  r.squared adj.r.squared    sigma statistic    p.value df    logLik      AIC      BIC deviance df.residual
1 0.5442762     0.5396729 1.502943  118.2368 1.3719e-18  2 -183.4527 372.9055 380.7508 223.6251          99
```

---

## Side notes

I find the `glance` function is useful as it neatly summarises the key values. The results are stored as a `data.frame` which makes further manipulation easy:

```
>> class(glance(fit))
[1] "data.frame"
```

Comment: This is a great answer!

Answer (score 24):

While both of the answers above are good, the procedure for extracting parts of objects is more general.

In many cases, functions return lists, and the individual components can be accessed using `str()` which will print the components along with their names. You can then access them using the $ operator, i.e. `myobject$componentname`.

In the case of lm objects, there are a number of predefined methods one can use such as `coef()`, `resid()`, `summary()` etc, but you won't always be so lucky.

Answer (score 17):

Extension of @Vincent 's [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/5588638/4581200):

For `lm()` generated models:

```
summary(fit)$coefficients[,4]   ##P-values 
summary(fit)$r.squared          ##R squared values
```

For `gls()` generated models:

```
summary(fit)$tTable[,4]         ##P-values
##R-squared values are not generated b/c gls uses max-likelihood not Sums of Squares
```

To isolate an individual p-value itself, you'd add a row number to the code:

For example to access the p-value of the intercept in both model summaries:

```
summary(fit)$coefficients[1,4]
summary(fit)$tTable[1,4]
```

- Note, you can replace the column number with the column name in each of the above instances:

  ```
  summary(fit)$coefficients[1,"Pr(>|t|)"]  ##lm 
  summary(fit)$tTable[1,"p-value"]         ##gls
  ```

If you're still unsure of how to access a value form the summary table use `str()` to figure out the structure of the summary table:

```
str(summary(fit))
```

Answer (score 10):

This is the easiest way to pull the p-values:

```
coef(summary(modelname))[, "Pr(>|t|)"]
```

Comment: I tried this method, but it will fail if the linear model contains any NA terms

Answer (score 5):

I used this lmp function quite a lot of times.

And at one point I decided to add new features to enhance data analysis. I am not in expert in R or statistics but people are usually looking at different information of a linear regression :

- p-value
- a and b
- r²
- and of course the aspect of the point distribution

Let's have an example. You have here

Here a reproducible example with different variables:

```
Ex<-structure(list(X1 = c(-36.8598, -37.1726, -36.4343, -36.8644, 
-37.0599, -34.8818, -31.9907, -37.8304, -34.3367, -31.2984, -33.5731
), X2 = c(64.26, 63.085, 66.36, 61.08, 61.57, 65.04, 72.69, 63.83, 
67.555, 76.06, 68.61), Y1 = c(493.81544, 493.81544, 494.54173, 
494.61364, 494.61381, 494.38717, 494.64122, 493.73265, 494.04246, 
494.92989, 494.98384), Y2 = c(489.704166, 489.704166, 490.710962, 
490.653212, 490.710612, 489.822928, 488.160904, 489.747776, 490.600579, 
488.946738, 490.398958), Y3 = c(-19L, -19L, -19L, -23L, -30L, 
-43L, -43L, -2L, -58L, -47L, -61L)), .Names = c("X1", "X2", "Y1", 
"Y2", "Y3"), row.names = c(NA, 11L), class = "data.frame")


library(reshape2)
library(ggplot2)
Ex2<-melt(Ex,id=c("X1","X2"))
colnames(Ex2)[3:4]<-c("Y","Yvalue")
Ex3<-melt(Ex2,id=c("Y","Yvalue"))
colnames(Ex3)[3:4]<-c("X","Xvalue")

ggplot(Ex3,aes(Xvalue,Yvalue))+
          geom_smooth(method="lm",alpha=0.2,size=1,color="grey")+
          geom_point(size=2)+
          facet_grid(Y~X,scales='free')


#Use the lmp function

lmp <- function (modelobject) {
  if (class(modelobject) != "lm") stop("Not an object of class 'lm' ")
  f <- summary(modelobject)$fstatistic
    p <- pf(f[1],f[2],f[3],lower.tail=F)
    attributes(p) <- NULL
    return(p)
    }

# create function to extract different informations from lm

lmtable<-function (var1,var2,data,signi=NULL){
  #var1= y data : colnames of data as.character, so "Y1" or c("Y1","Y2") for example
  #var2= x data : colnames of data as.character, so "X1" or c("X1","X2") for example
  #data= data in dataframe, variables in columns
  # if signi TRUE, round p-value with 2 digits and add *** if <0.001, ** if < 0.01, * if < 0.05.

  if (class(data) != "data.frame") stop("Not an object of class 'data.frame' ")
  Tabtemp<-data.frame(matrix(NA,ncol=6,nrow=length(var1)*length(var2)))
  for (i in 1:length(var2))
       {
  Tabtemp[((length(var1)*i)-(length(var1)-1)):(length(var1)*i),1]<-var1
  Tabtemp[((length(var1)*i)-(length(var1)-1)):(length(var1)*i),2]<-var2[i]
  colnames(Tabtemp)<-c("Var.y","Var.x","p-value","a","b","r^2")

  for (n in 1:length(var1))
  {
  Tabtemp[(((length(var1)*i)-(length(var1)-1))+n-1),3]<-lmp(lm(data[,var1[n]]~data[,var2[i]],data))

  Tabtemp[(((length(var1)*i)-(length(var1)-1))+n-1),4]<-coef(lm(data[,var1[n]]~data[,var2[i]],data))[1]

  Tabtemp[(((length(var1)*i)-(length(var1)-1))+n-1),5]<-coef(lm(data[,var1[n]]~data[,var2[i]],data))[2]

  Tabtemp[(((length(var1)*i)-(length(var1)-1))+n-1),6]<-summary(lm(data[,var1[n]]~data[,var2[i]],data))$r.squared
  }
  }

  signi2<-data.frame(matrix(NA,ncol=3,nrow=nrow(Tabtemp)))
  signi2[,1]<-ifelse(Tabtemp[,3]<0.001,paste0("***"),ifelse(Tabtemp[,3]<0.01,paste0("**"),ifelse(Tabtemp[,3]<0.05,paste0("*"),paste0(""))))
  signi2[,2]<-round(Tabtemp[,3],2)
  signi2[,3]<-paste0(format(signi2[,2],digits=2),signi2[,1])

  for (l in 1:nrow(Tabtemp))
    {
  Tabtemp$"p-value"[l]<-ifelse(is.null(signi),
         Tabtemp$"p-value"[l],
         ifelse(isTRUE(signi),
                paste0(signi2[,3][l]),
                Tabtemp$"p-value"[l]))
  }

   Tabtemp
}

# ------- EXAMPLES ------

lmtable("Y1","X1",Ex)
lmtable(c("Y1","Y2","Y3"),c("X1","X2"),Ex)
lmtable(c("Y1","Y2","Y3"),c("X1","X2"),Ex,signi=TRUE)
```

There is certainly a faster solution than this function but it works.

Answer (score 4):

For the final p-value displayed at the end of `summary()`, the function uses `pf()` to calculate from the `summary(fit)$fstatistic` values.

```r
fstat <- summary(fit)$fstatistic
pf(fstat[1], fstat[2], fstat[3], lower.tail=FALSE)
```

Source: [[1]](http://r.789695.n4.nabble.com/Extract-p-value-from-lm-for-the-whole-model-tp1470479p1470527.html), [[2]](https://stackoverflow.com/a/28016999/9645167)

Answer (score 2):

Another option is to use the cor.test function, instead of lm:

```
> x <- c(44.4, 45.9, 41.9, 53.3, 44.7, 44.1, 50.7, 45.2, 60.1)
> y <- c( 2.6,  3.1,  2.5,  5.0,  3.6,  4.0,  5.2,  2.8,  3.8)

> mycor = cor.test(x,y)
> mylm = lm(x~y)

# r and rsquared:
> cor.test(x,y)$estimate ** 2
      cor 
0.3262484 
> summary(lm(x~y))$r.squared
[1] 0.3262484

# P.value 

> lmp(lm(x~y))  # Using the lmp function defined in Chase's answer
[1] 0.1081731
> cor.test(x,y)$p.value
[1] 0.1081731
```

Answer (score 2):

Use:

```
(summary(fit))$coefficients[***num***,4]
```

where `num` is a number which denotes the row of the coefficients matrix. It will depend on how many features you have in your model and which one you want to pull out the p-value for. For example, if you have only one variable there will be one p-value for the intercept which will be [1,4] and the next one for your actual variable which will be [2,4]. So your ***`num`*** will be 2.

Answer (score 1):

```
x = cumsum(c(0, runif(100, -1, +1)))
y = cumsum(c(0, runif(100, -1, +1)))
fit = lm(y ~ x)
> names(summary(fit))
[1] "call"          "terms"        
 [3] "residuals"     "coefficients" 
 [5] "aliased"       "sigma"        
 [7] "df"            "r.squared"    
 [9] "adj.r.squared" "fstatistic"   
[11] "cov.unscaled" 
    summary(fit)$r.squared
```

Comment: Care to provide an explanation, even if briefly, on why this code works?

Comment: how does this improve on the existing answers (and in particular the accepted answer)?