# How to get values of Z - statistic from glm object?

Tags: r, glm

How can I get values of Z - statistics as a vector from `glm` object?
For example, I have

```
fit <- glm(y ~ 0 + x,binomial)
```

How can I access the column `Pr(>|z|)` the same way I get estimates of coefficients with `fit$coef`?

Comment: if one of these answers solves your problem, you should click on the checkmark to accept it ...

Answer (score 12):

I believe that

```
coef(summary(fit))[,"Pr(>|z|)"]
```

will get you what you want. (`summary.glm()` returns an object that has a `coef()` method that returns the coefficient table.) (By the way, if accessor methods exist it's better to use them than to directly access the components of the fitted model -- e.g. `coef(fit)` is better than `fit$coef`.)

[pull out p-values and r-squared from a linear regression](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5587676/pull-out-p-values-and-r-squared-from-a-linear-regression) gives a similar answer.

I would suggest `methods(class="summary.glm")` to find available accessor methods, but it's actually a little bit trickier than that because the default methods (in this case `coef.default()`) may also be relevant ...

**PS** if you want the Z values, `coef(summary(fit))[,"z value"]` should do it (your question is a little bit ambiguous: usually when people say "Z statistic" they mean the want the *value of the test statistic*, rather than the p value)

Comment: Re: using accessor method better than `fit$coef`: ... especially so since fit$coef does not return any p-values.

Comment: Yes -- the last sentence was referring back to the OP's use of `fit$coef` (the OP is already aware that this doesn't get p-values)

Comment: Apropos not much ... I find the use of the `coef`function for use the summary.glm-objects and summary.lm-objects to be rather a stretch in terminology. p-values , std-errors and z-stats are not "coefficients" in my book. It breaks the consistency of the use of that function.

Comment: OK, it should be `coefTable()` ... but what can you do?  Let's not get started on R inconsistencies here ...

Answer (score 1):

You can access to the info you want by doing

```
utils::data(anorexia, package="MASS") # Some data

anorex.1 <- glm(Postwt ~ Prewt + Treat + offset(Prewt),
                family = gaussian, data = anorexia)  # a glm model 
summary(anorex.1)

summary(anorex.1)$coefficients[,3] # vector of t-values
(Intercept)       Prewt   TreatCont     TreatFT 
   3.716770   -3.508689   -2.163761    2.138933 

summary(anorex.1)$coefficients[,4] # vector of p-values
 (Intercept)        Prewt    TreatCont      TreatFT 
0.0004101067 0.0008034250 0.0339993147 0.0360350847 

summary(anorex.1)$coefficients[,3:4] # matrix 
              t value     Pr(>|t|)
(Intercept)  3.716770 0.0004101067
Prewt       -3.508689 0.0008034250
TreatCont   -2.163761 0.0339993147
TreatFT      2.138933 0.0360350847
```

`str` function will show you where each element within an object is located, and `[[` accessors (better than `$`, as pointed out by @DWin and @Ben Bolker) will extract the info for you. Try `str(summary(anorex.1))` to see what this function does.

Comment: I would prefer accessors instead of extracting list elements [`coef(summary(...))` vs. `summary(...)$coefficients`], and extracting columns by name [`...[,"Pr(>|t|)"]` vs `...[,3]` ... but +1 for thorough illustration

Answer (score 0):

I use the summary syntax like: summary(my_model)[[1]][[2]]. You can try to use different combinations of numbers in "[[]]" to extract the data required. Of course, if I correctly understood your question :)