# Extracting p-value from lapply list of glm fits

Tags: r, glm, lapply

I am using lapply to perform several glm regressions on one dependent variable by one independent variable at a time.  Right now I am specifically interested in the `Pr(>|z|)` of each independent variable.  However, I am unsure on how to report just `Pr(>|z|)` using the list from lapply.

If I was just running one model at a time:
`coef(summary(fit))[,"Pr(>|z|)"]`
or
`summary(fit)$coefficients[,4]`
Would work (as described [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/12341400/1670053)), but trying something similar with `lapply` does not seem to work.  Can I get just the p-values using `lapply` and `glm` with an accessor method or from directly calling from the models?

```
#mtcars dataset
vars <- names(mtcars)[2:8]
fits <- lapply(vars, function(x) {glm(substitute(mpg ~ i, list(i = as.name(x))), family=binomial, data = mtcars)})
lapply(fits,summary) # this works
lapply(fits, coefficients) # this works
#lapply(fits, summary(fits)$coefficients[,4])# this for example does not work
```

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You want to do:

```
lapply(fits, function(f) summary(f)$coefficients[,4])
```

However, if each item is just a p-value, you would probably rather have a vector than a list, so you could use `sapply` instead of `lapply`:

```
sapply(fits, function(f) summary(f)$coefficients[,4])
```

Answer (score 6):

When you run `lapply(fits, summary)` it creates a list of summary.glm objects each of which is printed using `print.summary.glm`

If you save this

```
 summaries <- lapply(fits, summary)
```

You can then go through and extract the coefficient matrix

```
 coefmat <- lapply(summaries, '[[', 'coefficients')
```

and then the 4th column

```
 lapply(coefmat, '[', , 4)
```