# How to obtain just particular lines of summary on lm object

Tags: r, summary, lm

This problem comes from easier problem which I managed to solve myself. So here is my original question.

In my data I have lots of categories, but i'm not interested in estimating coefficients for all of them, I just want to test the hypothesis, that there is no difference in categories. And calling `summary` on my object produces most information that I don't need for my report.

```
set.seed(42)
dat <- data.frame(cat=factor(sample(1:10, 100, replace=T)), y=rnorm(100))
l1 <- lm(y~cat-1, data=dat)
summary(l1)
```

How do I extract only the last line from call to `summary(l1)`?

In this particular case I can just used `anova` function

```
anova(l1)
```

and got only the info that I needed, just in different formatting than `summary(l1)` produces.

What if I have some kind of a summary on an object and I want to extract just particular part of `summary(object)` how do I do that? For example, how do I get `R` to print only the line of call `summary(l1)`?

p.s. I am aware of `summary(l1)$fstatistic`.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

OK, I'm in a literal mood, but using `capture.output` will return the character representation of an evaluated object. So for example, using your `l1` object:

```
l1Out <- capture.output(summary(l1))
grep("^F-st", l1Out, value = TRUE)
# [1] "F-statistic: 1.323 on 10 and 90 DF,  p-value: 0.2303 "
```

Note, however, that this is not the *last line* of output:

```
tail(l1Out, 1)
# [1] ""
```

And for many components of the summary object, there are better ways to extract information, such as @seancarmody wrote

```
l1$call
# lm(formula = y ~ cat - 1, data = dat)
```

Comment: This function `capture.output()` is very straightforward! Thanks.

Answer (score 4):

Try using `str` to explore. For example, have a look at

```
str(summary(l1))
```

the output of which includes

```
$ fstatistic   : Named num [1:3] 1.32 10 90
```

then you can try

```
summary(l1)$fstatistic

#   value     numdf     dendf 
#1.323275 10.000000 90.000000
```

the p-value is a little tricker. Have a read of [this post](http://tolstoy.newcastle.edu.au/R/e2/help/07/08/23280.html) for more info, but here is a solution:

```
anova(l1)$"Pr(>F)"[1]
# [1] 0.2303172
```

...not pretty, but it seems to work!

Comment: Related answers [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5587676/pull-out-p-values-and-r-squared-from-a-linear-regression/5587781#5587781)