# Generate P value and slope by looping in regression

Tags: r, loops, regression

Is there a way to generate slope and P value of regression for around 500 time series. An example file given below:

I have a .csv file in following format:

```
 year  var1 var2  var3 var4 var5 var6 ....var500
 1951  2    4     3    3   9     3 ........3
 1952  4    7     4    1   2     2 ........4
 1953  5    5     6    9   4     3 ........5
 1954  6    9     6    2   3     9 ........6
 1955  6    4     4    2   1     2 ........1
 1956  6    4     3    7   2     8 ........8
```

I want to do a linear regression for name1, name2, name3, name 4.... and for each regression be able to print out the slope and  p-value.
So far I have been doing this manually for each variable

```
  var1_mdl<-lm(var1 ~ year);summary(var1_mdl)
```

Is there a way I can do a linear regression and be able to write the slope and P-value of each var in a separate file.

Thanks a lot

Answer (score 0):

You could use `apply` function on a subset of your dataframe `df` representing only columns of interest `df[,only_varX]` like this

```
apply(df[,only_varX], 2, function(col, year){ lm(col ~ year) }, df$year)
```

and you'll get a list of `lm` objects for every column of `df[,only_varX]` as the result.

With that list you can [extract p-value](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5587676/pull-out-p-values-and-r-squared-from-a-linear-regression) and slope (use `$coefficients`) and write them to a file/files.