# Print R-squared for all of the models fit with lmList

Tags: r, lm, nlme

I used `lmList` to fit 480 relationships and I would like the R2 of each of these.

Here is an example dataset and model which are pretty close to what it really looks like, except I have 480 eu (experimental units):

```
eu  mass  day
11  .02    1
11  .03    2
11  .04    3
11  .06    4
12  .01    1
12  .03    2
12  .04    3
12  .05    4

fit<-lmList(mass ~ day | eu, data=df)
```

Printing `fit` or `summary` does not give me the information I want.  I am ultimately trying to make a new dataframe that will look like:

```
eu    intercept    slope    R2
11     .01          .95     .98
12     .01          .96     .98
```

I've got the coefficients through `coef`, now I need the R-squared.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Here you go:

```
sapply(fit,function(x) summary(x)$r.squared)
       11        12 
0.9657143 0.9657143
```

Or to do everything at once:

```
sumfun <- function(x) c(coef(x),summary(x)$r.squared)
t(sapply(fit,sumfun))
```

(you need to transpose the results from `sapply` to get the table as specified above).  Then use `names() <-` or `setNames()` to get the column names the way you want them.

Comment: Thanks!  I just couldn't even tell if R2 was in there somewhere.

Comment: It's not too hard to find that information on SO: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5587676/pull-out-p-values-and-r-squared-from-a-linear-regression (you should probably read all the answers there, there's a lot of useful information)

Comment: There is a lot of useful information there!  Searching specific to `lmList` did not turn up much.

Answer (score 1):

using Ben Bolker's code, you can make a function that transposes the results and gives the table, all at once:

```
sumfun <- function(x) 
{
  aux <- function(x) c(coef(x), summary(x)$r.squared)
  t(sapply(x,aux))
}
sumfun(fit)
```