# Generate an array of regression models without for loop

Tags: r, data.table, linear-regression

I have a data set with columns Y, X1, X2 and V. While Y, X1 and X2 are continuous, V is a categorical variable. Assuming V has 10 categories, I want to create 10 linear regression models and store the results (coefficients, p-values, R-Sq, etc) in another table. Is there a way to do it with data.table without using for loops? Thanks.

Comment: See `lmList` in the nlme package. See [mcve] for information how to provide a reproducible example when asking a question on SO.

Comment: Thanks. I tried lmList, it worked. I got only the coeffs, but I am sure I can figure out how to get R-Sq, p-values etc.

Comment: See http://stackoverflow.com/questions/23501852/print-r-squared-for-all-of-the-models-fit-with-lmlist

Answer (score 3):

The base R function `by` is what you want.

```
# make up some sample data
dataSet <- data.frame(Y = iris$Sepal.Length, 
                      X1 = iris$Sepal.Width, 
                      X2 = iris$Petal.Length, 
                      V = iris$Species)
# apply the `lm` function by the value of `V`
by(data = dataSet[c("Y","X1","X2")], 
   INDICES = dataSet$V, 
   FUN = lm, 
   formula = Y ~ .)
```

In the `by` function, `data` is the data you want to apply the function to. `INDICES` is a vector of factors or list of factors with one value corresponding to each row of `data` indicating how you want the data split up. `FUN` is the function you want applied to the subsets of your data.  In this case, `lm()` needs the extra parameter `formula` indicating how you want to model your data, so you can easily pass that as and extra `formula` parameter in the `by` function.

Answer (score 0):

The [broom package](https://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/broom/vignettes/broom.html) exists exactly for this type of problem. It 'tidies' the output of models into neat data frames for easy storage and comparison. Here is an  [example](https://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/broom/vignettes/broom_and_dplyr.html) that uses `broom` and `dplyr` to solve a near identical problem. It uses `dplyr` to group the data by a categorical variable, fits a model to each group, and extracts the coefficients into a data.frame in just a few lines of code. I am unfamiliar with `data.table`'s grouped operation, but it may be possible to perform something similar with the package.

Additionally, `broom` has the `augment` function, which can be used to calculate goodness-of-fit metrics and other summary statistics.

Alternatively, if you want to do it without installing additional packages, you could split your data frame into a list (using the `split` function), `lapply` the modeling process to the list, extract the results (probably through another `lapply` that extracts info from the `lm` object,) and then `rbind` it all together.