# Extracting Coefficients, Std Errors, R2 etc from multiple regressions

Tags: r, linear-regression

I have the following regression model;

```
models <- lapply(1:25, function(x) lm(Y_df[,x] ~ X1))
```

Which runs 25 regressions on 25 columns in the `Y_df` dataframe.

One of the outputs can be shown as;

```
models[15] # Gives me the coefficients for model 15

Call:
lm(formula = Y_df[, x] ~ X1)

Coefficients:
(Intercept)         X1 
  0.1296812    1.0585835
```

Which I can store in a separate df. The problem I am running into is regarding Std. Error, R2, residules etc.

I would like to store these also into a separate dataframe.

I can run individual regressions and extract the summaries as a normal R regression output would look like.

```
ls_1 <- summary(models[[1]])
ls_1
ls_1$sigma
```

However I am hoping to take the values directly from the line of code which runs the 25 regressions.

This code works

```
> (models[[15]]$coefficients)
  (Intercept)          X1 
-0.3643446787  1.0789369642
```

However; this code does not.

```
> (models[[15]]$sigma)
NULL
```

I have tried a variety of different combinations to try and extract these results with no luck.

The following did exactly what I wanted perfectly. I had hoped there was a way to replace the word `coef` with `Std Error` or `R2` etc. but this does not work.

```
models <- lapply(1:25, function(x) lm(Y_df[,x] ~ X1))
# extract just coefficients
coefficients <- sapply(Y_df, coef)
```

Ideally I would like to store the `Std Error` from the above model

Comment: Possible duplicate of [pull out p-values and r-squared from a linear regression](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5587676/pull-out-p-values-and-r-squared-from-a-linear-regression)

Comment: Very simple. You need to calculate the summary in order to get the additional statistics.

Comment: Not a duplicate. I knew how to extract singly the coefficients, Rsquared etc but for this particular task I wanted to extract the values for 25 regressions and store them in a df

Comment: Use `summary` in your sapply` (don't forget `simplify = FALSE`) and you should have summary statistics available to fetch using the `sapply`-way.

Comment: Hi Ben I can live with that I just observe that most new users who would be searching check answers long before they read **all** the comments.  There are a plethora of related but unlinked answers about how to get `lm` results with variations on the # of IV or DV and really just can be via loop, apply family or purrr.  They may not be direct duplicates because of some nuance but they are all related

Answer (score 0):

If a model is named mod, you can get to all of the residuals in the same way as the coefficients:

```
mod$residuals
```

There are also functions that extract the coefficients and residuals:

```
coef(mod)
resid(mod)
```

The other outputs, you can extract via `summary`:

```
summary(mod)$coef[,"Std. Error"]  # standard errors
summary(mod)$r.squared            # r squared
summary(mod)$adj.r.squared        # adjusted r squared
```

So you can either create a list containing each of these results for each model:

```
outputList <- lapply(models, function(x){
  coefs <- coef(mod)
  stdErr <- summary(mod)$coef[,"Std. Error"]
  rsq <- summary(mod)$r.squared
  rsq_adj <- summary(mod)$adj.r.squared
  rsd <- resid(mod)
  list(coefs = coefs, 
       stdErr = stdErr, 
       rsq = rsq, 
       rsq_adj = rsq_adj, 
       rsd = rsd)
})
```

You can then get to the rsq for mod1 via `outputList$mod1$rsq`, for example.

Or you can create separate dataframes for each:

```
library(tidyverse)

# coefficients
coefs <- lapply(models, coef) %>%
  do.call(rbind, .) %>%
  as.data.frame() %>% # convert from matrix to dataframe
  rownames_to_column("model") # add original model name as a column in the dataframe

# standard errors
stdErr <- lapply(models, function(x){
  summary(mod)$coef[,"Std. Error"]
}) %>%
  do.call(rbind, .) %>%
  as.data.frame() %>% 
  rownames_to_column("model") 

# r squareds
rsq <- sapply(models, function(x){
  summary(mod)$r.squared
}) %>%
  as.data.frame() %>% 
  rownames_to_column("model")

# adjusted r squareds
rsq_adj <- sapply(models, function(x){
  summary(mod)$adj.r.squared
})%>%
  as.data.frame() %>% 
  rownames_to_column("model")

# residuals
rsd <- lapply(models, resid) %>%
  do.call(rbind, .) %>%
  as.data.frame() %>% 
  rownames_to_column("model")
```

Worth noting that, if you're in RStudio and you assign the summary to something (ie `temp <- summary(mod)`), you can type the name of the object, then "$" and a dropdown of all the other objects that can be extracted from the summary appears.

Comment: Thanks for your comment, its very useful.