# Extract models based on conditions in r

Tags: r, regression, linear-regression

I ran about 30,000 multiple regression models using `pylr` packages.

```
fit = plyr::dlply(data, "id", function(x) lm(t ~ d1 + d2 + d3, data = x))
```

We have more than 30,000 IDs so it came out with more than 30,000 models. I cannot read the models one by one. Are there any efficient ways to look at the models based on the conditions. I want to look at models according to

```
top 5 p-value (from the smallest)
top r squred
all the models with d3 significant
```

At this moment, I can only look at the model one by one using `l_ply(fit, summary, .print = TRUE)`

I tried to use `tidy` function in `broom` packages in order to change the results into cleaned format so that i can export .csv file but it wouldn't work out.

```
test = broom::tidy(fit)
```

I received error messages telling me `Error in tidy.list(fit) : No tidying method recognized for this list`

Any advice would be appreciated!

Here are some data added:

```
df <- data.frame(id=sample(LETTERS[1:10], replace= T, 10),
             d1=rnorm(20), d2=rnorm(20), d3=rnorm(20), t= rnorm(20), stringsAsFactors = F)

fit1 = plyr::dlply(df, "id", function(x) lm(t ~ d1 + d2 + d3, data = x))
```

Comment: Take a look at the "Many Models" [article](http://r4ds.had.co.nz/many-models.html) that makes use of `broom` functions

Comment: @camille thank you very much! I followed the article and got exactly what I want! as a follow-up question, are there any way we can do the same thing on the r-squared and p.value for each independent variable?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here's a workflow based on the [Many Models article](http://r4ds.had.co.nz/many-models.html), using `broom` functions on nested data frames. Note that I increased the size of the data frame, just to have more observations to work with.

With this method, you group data by ID, nest it, and create the `lm` objects by mapping over the nested data. `broom::glance` gives you summary output on the models:

```r
library(tidyverse)
library(broom)

set.seed(124)
df <- data.frame(id=sample(LETTERS[1:10], size = 10, replace = T),
                 d1=rnorm(100), d2=rnorm(100), d3=rnorm(100), t= rnorm(100), stringsAsFactors = F)

models_df <- df %>%
  group_by(id) %>%
  nest() %>%
  mutate(mod = map(data, function(x) lm(t ~ d1 + d2 + d3, data = x))) %>%
  mutate(glance = map(mod, glance)) %>%
  unnest(glance)

models_df
#> # A tibble: 6 x 14
#>   id    data   mod   r.squared adj.r.squared sigma statistic p.value    df
#>   <chr> <list> <lis>     <dbl>         <dbl> <dbl>     <dbl>   <dbl> <int>
#> 1 A     <tibb… <S3:…    0.495         0.243  0.955     1.96   0.221      4
#> 2 E     <tibb… <S3:…    0.142        -0.0189 0.907     0.883  0.471      4
#> 3 F     <tibb… <S3:…    0.179         0.0247 1.05      1.16   0.355      4
#> 4 D     <tibb… <S3:…    0.818         0.727  0.522     8.97   0.0123     4
#> 5 C     <tibb… <S3:…    0.0514       -0.0580 0.994     0.470  0.706      4
#> 6 J     <tibb… <S3:…    0.202        -0.197  0.933     0.506  0.693      4
#> # ... with 5 more variables: logLik <dbl>, AIC <dbl>, BIC <dbl>,
#> #   deviance <dbl>, df.residual <int>
```

Now that you have a data frame with summary statistics like R-squared, you can use regular `dplyr` commands like `top_n` to get rankings:

```r
# smallest 5 p-value
models_df %>% top_n(-5, p.value)
#> # A tibble: 5 x 14
#>   id    data   mod   r.squared adj.r.squared sigma statistic p.value    df
#>   <chr> <list> <lis>     <dbl>         <dbl> <dbl>     <dbl>   <dbl> <int>
#> 1 A     <tibb… <S3:…     0.495        0.243  0.955     1.96   0.221      4
#> 2 E     <tibb… <S3:…     0.142       -0.0189 0.907     0.883  0.471      4
#> 3 F     <tibb… <S3:…     0.179        0.0247 1.05      1.16   0.355      4
#> 4 D     <tibb… <S3:…     0.818        0.727  0.522     8.97   0.0123     4
#> 5 J     <tibb… <S3:…     0.202       -0.197  0.933     0.506  0.693      4
#> # ... with 5 more variables: logLik <dbl>, AIC <dbl>, BIC <dbl>,
#> #   deviance <dbl>, df.residual <int>

# top r-sq
models_df %>% top_n(1, r.squared)
#> # A tibble: 1 x 14
#>   id    data   mod   r.squared adj.r.squared sigma statistic p.value    df
#>   <chr> <list> <lis>     <dbl>         <dbl> <dbl>     <dbl>   <dbl> <int>
#> 1 D     <tibb… <S3:…     0.818         0.727 0.522      8.97  0.0123     4
#> # ... with 5 more variables: logLik <dbl>, AIC <dbl>, BIC <dbl>,
#> #   deviance <dbl>, df.residual <int>
```

For significant `d3` terms, I went back to the models data frame and mapped `broom::tidy` across the models, which gives summary stats on each term, then filtered to study the `d3` terms.

```r
# significant d3--assuming alpha = 0.05
models_df %>%
  mutate(tidied = map(mod, tidy)) %>%
  unnest(tidied, .drop = T) %>%
  filter(term == "d3") %>%
  filter(p.value < 0.05)
#> # A tibble: 1 x 17
#>   id    r.squared adj.r.squared sigma statistic p.value    df logLik   AIC
#>   <chr>     <dbl>         <dbl> <dbl>     <dbl>   <dbl> <int>  <dbl> <dbl>
#> 1 D         0.818         0.727 0.522      8.97  0.0123     4  -5.13  20.3
#> # ... with 8 more variables: BIC <dbl>, deviance <dbl>, df.residual <int>,
#> #   term <chr>, estimate <dbl>, std.error <dbl>, statistic1 <dbl>,
#> #   p.value1 <dbl>
```

Created on 2018-06-20 by the [reprex package](http://reprex.tidyverse.org) (v0.2.0).

Comment: Very nice answer! Full service :)

Comment: @Y.Yuan I was happy to practice this approach, since I'm still getting the hang of the nested data frames and the move to `map` to replace `do`

Comment: @camille when i tried to nest data using models_df <- df %>%
  group_by(id) %>%
  nest() %>%
  mutate(mod = map(data, function(x) lm(t ~ d1 + d2 + d3, data = x))) %>%
  mutate(glance = map(mod, glance)) %>%
  unnest(glance)    I've got an error message - cannot convert a list to a function...

Comment: Not sure, try naming it something other than glance...that wasn't the safest idea on my part to name a variable the same as a function

Answer (score 2):

Here's an example of extracting the 3 highest R^2 models.

```
r2 = unlist(lapply(fit, function(x) summary(x)$r.squared))
fit[order(r2, decreasing = T)[1:3]]
```

The others are analagous: See this post https://stackoverflow.com/a/5587781/2761575 for how to extract p-values if you want to rank by these instead