# Difference in p-values between summary() vs glance()?

Tags: r, lm, summary, broom

I'm noticing a difference in the p-values when calling `summary()` on a linear model object versus calling `broom::glance()`. I think the floating point precision when calling `summary()` is limited to `2.2e-16` while glance can reach beyond `1e-100`. Is my suspicion correct, or are these values inherently different?

```
x <- c(1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9)
y <- c(10, 20, 30, 40, 50, 60, 70, 80, 90)

mod <- lm(y~x)

summary(mod) # p < 2.2e-16

broom::glance(mod) # p = 4.66e-112
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It is just a matter of visualization,

`summary(mod)` says that p-value is less than 2.2e-16 (<2.2e-16), not equal.

For example, if you run

`summary(mod)$coefficient` you get 4.66e-112

Best

Comment: Do you how to extract the model p-value (<2.2e-6) instead of just the coefficient p-value?

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5587676/pull-out-p-values-and-r-squared-from-a-linear-regression

Comment: Just found this too. This ended up being the issue. Thanks!

Answer (score 2):

They are the same. Please see the P value from `summary` after we print the coefficient.

```
summary(mod) 

s$coefficients
#                 Estimate   Std. Error      t value      Pr(>|t|)
# (Intercept) 9.473903e-15 3.161050e-15 2.997075e+00  2.002483e-02
# x           1.000000e+01 5.617334e-16 1.780204e+16 4.661081e-112
```

Comment: So the 4.66e-112 is the p-value for the `x` coefficient, but not for the entire model? These are two different statistics then?

Comment: For coefficient.